# Is there an efficient way to sample from a space of solutions to $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real rectangular matrix, and $b$ be a vector of real numbers. Assuming that there are many solutions for real vector $x$, is there an efficient way to obtain random samples from the space of solutions to $Ax=b$?

Comment: If the set  of possible values of $x$ has more than one point, it is infinite and non bounded. Then no uniform probability can be defined on the set.

Comment: It is ok if the function which returns samples is parametrized in some way, for example by giving the maximum acceptable norm of the solutions.